# Использование функций/процедур определенных на сервере

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Предположим имеется следующая *скалярная функция* хранящаяся в бд сервера:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.spTest ()
RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @result INT;
    SET @result = 1;
    RETURN @result;
  END
GO
```

Как вызвать данную функцию с использованием `entity framework`а и получить результат?

---

Пробовал делать так:

```
var cmd = _context.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[spTest]";

if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    cmd.Connection.Open();
try
{
    var result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

`result` не содержит значений. на основании этого [примера](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj691402)

Так же нашел следующий [совет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20911004/5610621)

на основании которого попробовал сделать так:

```
var query = _context.Database
    .SqlQuery(typeof(int),"dbo.spTest").ToListAsync();
var downtime = (int)query.Result.Single();
```

на что получаю следующее исключение:

> The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: У Вас не процедура, а функция думаю `cmd.CommandText` должен быть `SELECT [dbo].[spTest]`

Comment: @gofr1 если бы все было так просто, **Исключение:** *Не удалось привязать составной идентификатор "dbo.spTest"*

Comment: Ошибочка! `SELECT dbo.spTest ()`

Comment: @gofr1 спасибо за подсказку. я нашел почему у меня первоначально не работала конструкция `select [dbo].[Имя функции]`. надо было перед началом строки поставить символ `@` иначе вылазила ошибка

Comment: @gofr1 может опубликуете как ответ

Comment: Добавил :) Про `@` не понял, не помню такого синтаксиса, только если параметры передаются...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно изменить `cmd.CommandText`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [dbo].[spTest] ()";
```

Если функция с параметрами:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [dbo].[spTest](@param)";
```